# How to install downloaded jdk setup into ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, lubuntu

I have an `ubuntu11.04`, and I wanted to install `jdk7` into ubuntu. 
So I downloaded the jdk7 setup for ubuntu11.04. And I tried to install using 'sudo get-apt install `PackageName`.
But jdk is not installed it gives an error `E: package not found`. 
My downloaded jdk folder is on the `desktop`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [Help Center](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to a [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: There you go buddy.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntulinux

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should considering upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 version. It is the latest LTS version so you will not have to upgrade it for many years. The problem is that since 11.04 is not supported anymore there are probably not any packages for this version.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install package name does a search in launchpad or in repo which is added in source list and installs it. You can't download and install by using your way.

there is two alternative, one is openjdk and other is from oracle java installer.

for openjdk just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

for oracle java installer run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```